# The first picture I take with a USB webcam as soon as I connect it looks good, but the following ones are dark

Tags: usb, webcam, fswebcam

I am experiencing the following issue:

I connect a USB webcam (Logitech Quickcam Pro 4000) to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and take a picture using fswebcam and looks good. Sometimes I take a second picture, or a third one and it still looks good. 
But after that, all the pictures I take look dark (90% of the image is black, and there are some bright shapes).

I have tried to take the pictures using OpenCV's VideoCapture and extracting a frame from it and it happens the same (the first one is fine, the following ones look dark). I have also set the fswebcam's parameters manually (brightness at 50% and I have skipped the first 15 frames using -S) and the problem continues.

If I disconnect the Webcam and re-connect it, It allows me to take another good picture, but the problem continues for the next pictures.

Do you have an idea on what could be the problem?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!